# How can I use the python-telegram-bot library to approve user join requests?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make a telegram bot which automatically approves user's join requests in a private group. I came across the **python-telegram-bot** library and noticed that it had some useful functionalities such as *ChatJoinRequest()* and *approveChatJoinRequest()*, but i've been trying for hours, and just cant seem to figure out how to get them to work.

Unfortunately I was not able find much helpful info online regarding this specific topic.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide, what you've tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation I have seen:

- https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.chatjoinrequesthandler.html
- https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a6/telegram.chatjoinrequest.html

at first add the Handler to the dispatcher:

in your run.py

```
from telegram.ext import ChatJoinRequestHandler

...

dispatcher.add_handler(ChatJoinRequestHandler(join_request))
```

and your function should be of this type

```
def join_request(update, context):
    context.bot.approve_chat_join_request(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, user_id=update.effective_user.id
    )
```